# GWT Styling Problems

Tags: java, css, gwt, stylesheet

I need to be able to change the following styles in gwt only through the use of the css file and no java at all.

1. Font Size of the top tab of decorated panel[image]
2. Then, the Header of the Stack Panel [image]
3. The header of the caption panel [image]

Comment: You won't be able to change anything about them without some JavaScript. You'll either have to change their style attributes using `Style.getProperty()` or change their CSS class with `setStyleName()`.

Comment: Doesn't GWT assign them any css classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page might be useful for you: 
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html

Basically, most of the GWT widgets have a class called gwt-(Classname) (e.g. gwt-StackPanel).  Some have multiple ones. This should be described in the API as well, e.g.:
http://asquare.net/gwt/javadoc/1.0.21/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackPanel.html